# Does feature scaling have any benefits if all features are on the same scale?

Tags: data-preprocessing, features, feature-engineering

By [scaling features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling), we can prevent one feature from dominating the decisions of a model. For example, say heights (cm), and age (years) are two features in my data. Since range of heights is larger than of years, a trained model could weight importance of heights much more than years. This could result in a poor model in return.

However, say that all of my features are binary, they take a value of either 0 or 1. In such a case, does feature scaling still have any benefits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you features are binary, then, you don't need to apply normalization on them. Since their values are on the same scale already.